# How can I improve aiming with my gamepad?

Tags: valkyria-chronicles

After playing the very first mission in [the PC version of Valkyria Chronicles](http://store.steampowered.com/app/294860/), I noticed how difficult it is to aim with a gamepad.

Specifically: <strike>The dead zone is too large in this game, meaning I have to push the analog stick very far before my reticle will move and when it does, it moves too fast. Luckily, I can still use my mouse for precision aiming, but having to switch input devices all the time can be quite tiring.</strike>
It appears the large dead zone is actually a bug in the game, where pushing the stick only slightly will move the aiming reticle in the opposite direction.

Also, aiming is done with the left stick; this is not very intuitive since looking around is done using the right one. In aiming mode, aiming (and thus looking around) suddenly switches to the left stick.

<strike>How can I fix these aiming-related issues?</strike>
How can I map aiming to the right stick?

Comment: Which controller are you using? No problems here with the 360 wireless controller which makes me wonder if its game related or not.

Comment: @kenjara, I'm using an Xbox One controller and it's likely a game related issue. After playing some more I realized the issue is not with the dead zone but with a bug: pushing the stick only slightly will move the reticle in the opposite direction, which can cause the reticle to jiggle and appear stuck in place.

Comment: Hmm strange I assume your other games work fine with the One controller? If that's the case then it looks like the problem is with the games implementation of the One controller. It might be worth mentioning on the Steam forums for the game so this can be looked at / fixed.

Comment: I think your right in this is a general issue. Having played the game for a few hours now I can say I have the same problem. It's much more noticeable when you get to things like sniping.

Comment: @kenjara, I've been looking around the Steam forums, and it seems we can use the D-Pad for fine-aiming instead. I guess that's a good compromise over having to reach for the mouse.

Comment: That is a good tip it certainly makes aiming a lot easier. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dead zones on your controller aren't allowing for precise aiming, you can can use the D-Pad for fine aiming adjustments instead.

As for your second question, if you're playing on Steam you can map both aiming and camera movement to the right stick using Steam Input. Simply reconfigure your right stick to act as a mouse instead of a joystick.